# JQuery - reuse data after load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this function:

```
// AJAX MESSAGES SHOWING
show_msg.on('click', function(e){
    var $this = $(this),
    url = $this.attr('href'),
    url_info =  url + ' .basic_info > *',
    url_msg =  url + ' .contact_messages > *';

    basic_info.slideUp('fast', function(){
            basic_info.empty().load(url_info, function(){
                basic_info.slideDown('fast');
        });
    });

    contact_messages.slideUp('fast', function(){
            contact_messages.empty().load(url_msg, function(){
                contact_messages.slideDown('fast');
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

It is working, but I am using load two times, and I guess this is not very effective way to do this. Is there some way to load data once and then select what you need from that data?

Comment: For sure, you have to set it server side though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do:

```
(function(){

    var basicInfoLoaded = false, contactMessageLoaded = false;

// AJAX MESSAGES SHOWING
show_msg.on('click', function(e){
    var $this = $(this),
    url = $this.attr('href'),
    url_info =  url + ' .basic_info > *',
    url_msg =  url + ' .contact_messages > *';

    basic_info.slideUp('fast', function(){
                    if(basicInfoLoaded)
                        basic_info.slideDown('fast');
                    else{
                        basicInfoLoaded = true;
            basic_info.empty().load(url_info, function(){
                    basic_info.slideDown('fast');
            });
                    }
    });

    contact_messages.slideUp('fast', function(){
                    if(contactMessageLoaded)
                        contact_messages.slideDown('fast');
                    else{
                            contactMessageLoaded = true;
            contact_messages.empty().load(url_msg, function(){
                contact_messages.slideDown('fast');
                });
                    }
    });
    return false;
});

})();
```

Comment: It a bit more code then I hoped for, but I guess it is easing data transfer.